# $ABC$ Conjecture: Stewart & Yu 2001 result. Is Wikipedia mistaken?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, abc-conjecture

In the Wikipedia article on the $ABC$ conjecture in the theoretical results section, they give the [Stewart & Yu 2001](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.210.7427&rep=rep1&type=pdf) result as:

$$c<\exp \left(K_{3}\operatorname {rad} (abc)^{{\frac {1}{3}}+\varepsilon }\right)$$

but in the Stewart & Yu 2001 paper Theorem $1$ is given as:

$$c<\exp \left(K \operatorname {rad} (abc)^{\frac {1}{3}} \log(\operatorname {rad} (abc))^3\right)$$

Is the Wikipedia mention incorrect?

Comment: Look a few lines below the statement of theorem 2 in the paper.

Comment: thanks. Wikipedia should probably put Theorem 1 in there, too.

Comment: Updated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Theoretical_results

Comment: But Wikipedia was not wrong, simply less precise. Note that $\log(x)^3 \in O(x^\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon>0$.